# oAuth 2 server side vs client side

Tags: language-agnostic, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to wrap my head around oauth2 and am comparing the server and client side flows. To me the server side flow sounds much more simpler - the user authorizes once and then everything remains on the server (converting the code to an access token, requests to the remote api, etc).

So, why would someone want to use the client-side flow?

One possible answer to that might be to reduce server traffic. Does anyone have any evidence that client-side reduces a significant amount of traffic from the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it would be unlikely for approvals and access token grants to make up any sort of significant fraction of a server's traffic load unless it's implemented in a very obscure way. One might use the client-side flow if the application is very javascript-centric and has no other reason to contact a web server specifically for its service. For example, you could imagine some browser extension written in javascript that uses OAuth 2 to request someone's favorite YouTube videos, Facebook friends, or some other data, and display it to the user in some fashion. It may not make sense to dedicate a web server for serving those grants if it would perform no other function for the application.